# Principal argument of $z=\left(\left(\sqrt{3}+i)/(\sqrt{2}-i\right)\right)^{50}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> I am trying to compute the principal argument (which belongs to $(-\pi,\pi]$) of the complex number $$ z=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+i}{\sqrt{2}-i}\right)^{50}$$

---

My attempt:

Let $a=\sqrt{3}+i$ and $b=\sqrt{2}-i$. Then $\operatorname{Arg} (a)=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(b)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, so $\operatorname{arg}(z)=50\operatorname{arg}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{\sqrt{2}-i}\right)=50\operatorname{arg}(a)-50\operatorname{arg}(b)=\frac{50\pi}{3}-50\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{2\pi}{3}-50\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, modulo $2\pi$, where $\operatorname{Arg}$ and $\operatorname{arg}$ denote the principal argument and argument, respectively.

Now it suffices to add a suitable integer multiple of $2\pi$ to $\frac{2\pi}{3}-50\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, but I got stuck here. Any hints?

Comment: HINT: Rationalize the fraction.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Doesn't it make the expression more complicated?

Comment: To get the answer algebraically, use a CAS.  From Maple: $$\arctan \left( -{\frac {717897987691852588770249\,\sqrt {3}}{
311576564512748849025623}}+{\frac {973758949636344298055992\,\sqrt {2}
}{311576564512748849025623}} \right) $$ But is that of any use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{\sqrt{2}-i} = \frac{2\exp(\frac{\pi}{6}i)}{\sqrt{3}\exp(-\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})i)} =  \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\exp\left(\left[\frac{\pi}{6}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]i\right)$$

So

$$z = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{\sqrt{2}-i}\right)^{50} = \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{50}\exp\left(50\left[\frac{\pi}{6}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]i\right)$$

So the (non-principal) argument is $50 \left[\frac{\pi}{6}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$, and the principal argument happens to be

$$\theta  =50 \left[\frac{\pi}{6}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] - 18\pi \approx 0.4053 \,\,\text{radians} \approx 23.22^\circ $$

I don't know if there is a simple way to figure out how many multiples of $2\pi$ to subtract. I simply used a computational tool to calculate the numerical value of the (non-principal) argument.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to trigonometry form, we have:
$$z=\frac{2(\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6))}{\sqrt3(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}$$
where $\theta=\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)+2\pi\approx 2\pi-0.615\approx 5.25$.

Now, using De-Moivre's rule, we have:
$$z^{50}=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\right)^{50}=(\cos(50(\pi/6-\theta))+i\sin(50(\pi/6-\theta)))$$
So, the argument is:
$$\arg(z^{50})=50\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\theta\right)=50\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)-2\pi\right)=-\frac{550}{6}\pi-50\cdot\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
Here, we can compute $\arg(z^{50}) \mod 2\pi$, and so:
$$\arg(z^{50})=\left(\frac{1}{3}\pi-50\cdot\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\mod 2\pi$$

Comment: But I should compute it algebraically, without using approximations

Comment: @Troaro: please see my edits.

Comment: @Troaro: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?